# How to implement the current song in a Tweet using the Twitter framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, frameworks

I have this code:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

-(IBAction)playingSong{
MPMediaItem *theSong = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
    NSString *theTitle   = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *theArtist  = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    NSString *nowPlaying = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#NowPlaying %@ by %@", theTitle, theArtist];
    tweetTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", nowPlaying, tweetTextView.text];
    [self setChars];
}
```

How can I put the title, artist ecc in a Tweet using this?

```
- (IBAction)sendMusicTweet:(id)sender {
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

[self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks, I'm new to this world... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[tweetViewController setInitialText:tweetTextView.text]` should do the trick.